# How to convert torch.tensor to base64 image?

Tags: pytorch, base64

Here is my tensor:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms

content:
tensor([[[[0.8939, 0.8700, 0.8458,  ..., 0.7610, 0.7093, 0.6909],
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
          [0.4880, 0.5192, 0.5957,  ..., 0.8569, 0.9148, 0.9186]]]])
```

I want to convert this torch.Tensor to base64. I've tried this but I can not convert PILImage to base64 too.

```
img = transforms.ToPILImage(content)
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What is the size of your tensor?

Comment: torch.Size([1, 3, 512, 512])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert your image to bytes to encode afterward your image to base64 image

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms
import base64

tensor = torch.randn(3, 512, 512)
transform = transforms.ToPILImage()
pil_image = transform(tensor)

# Convert the PIL image to bytes
image_bytes = pil_image.tobytes()

# Encode the bytes to base64
base64_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode()
print(base64_string)
```

**Output:**

> 00Hbhc4yZEZnw/VlIyHF6OH2VRAXeRdYiH82tBgSBoocDAB+cycknk3c5G9ZmdbHNu90whgDK49cjELZ6uJCzqYxVclXbJRc0Nb2AgN9XWULFOK+ubWJAyNbAgNZRvmwocwJN4603

Comment: I've tried something like this but I can not get any result:
pil_image = transforms.ToPILImage(content)
image_bytes = pil_image.tobytes()
base64_string = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode()

Comment: Additionally, we have different size of arrays. My tensor has four dimension but yours is three.

Comment: @AlwaysJunior , what do you mean by not getting any result what is the problem?

Comment: I understand the problem. I needed to squeeze the tensor and your solution is helped me. Thank you!